# How to reduce very verbose output of Realtek rtl8821ae driver in syslog

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, logging

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Edimax PCI-E wi-fi card which uses Realtek driver.

When using my PCI-e wireless adapter (rtl8821ae) in wireless mode the kernel is writing very verbose information in the syslog.
How can I stop this information spamming in the syslog.

Below is a sample of what is going on. Surely there is a way to reduce this information. Hoping someone can help with this problem. 
I have tried google searches but can find no help so far.
Thanks in advance.

```
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu NetworkManager[781]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.923241] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_is_special_data():<10000-1> 802.1X Rx EAPOL pkt!!
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.924109] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_is_special_data():<100-1> 802.1X Tx EAPOL pkt!!
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu NetworkManager[781]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931070] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_is_special_data():<10000-1> 802.1X Rx EAPOL pkt!!
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[838]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 08:bd:43:30:43:b5 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[838]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 08:bd:43:30:43:b5 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931238] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_is_special_data():<100-1> 802.1X Tx EAPOL pkt!!
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931308] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> Using hardware based encryption for keyidx: 0, mac: 08:bd:43:30:43:b5
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931311] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> alg:CCMP
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931312] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> set enable_hw_sec, key_type:4(OPEN:0 WEP40:1 TKIP:2 AES:4 WEP104:5)
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931314] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_enable_hw_security_config():<0-0> PairwiseEncAlgorithm = 4 GroupEncAlgorithm = 0
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931321] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_enable_hw_security_config():<0-0> The SECR-value cc 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931325] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> set pairwise key
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931327] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_set_key():<0-0> add one entry
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931328] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_set_key():<0-0> set Pairwiase key
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931330] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_cam_add_one_entry():<0-0> EntryNo:4, ulKeyId=0, ulEncAlg=4, ulUseDK=0 MacAddr 08:bd:43:30:43:b5
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931331] rtl8821ae: 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931332] In process "wpa_supplicant" (pid 838):Key content :0E 47 4C C4  C3 4C 42 0A  AC F4 FC BD  8D 8D BD 49  
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931340] 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.931975] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_cam_add_one_entry():<0-0> end 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932102] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> Using hardware based encryption for keyidx: 2, mac: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932106] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> alg:CCMP
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932108] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_op_set_key():<0-0> set group key
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932110] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_set_key():<0-0> add one entry
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932111] rtl8821ae-0:rtl8821ae_set_key():<0-0> set group key
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932113] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_cam_add_one_entry():<0-0> EntryNo:2, ulKeyId=2, ulEncAlg=4, ulUseDK=0 MacAddr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932115] rtl8821ae: 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932117] In process "wpa_supplicant" (pid 838):Key content :8F 84 FB EE  0F F7 BE 26  34 D7 71 90  B9 FA C9 A6  
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932126] 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5728.932759] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_cam_add_one_entry():<0-0> end 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu NetworkManager[781]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu NetworkManager[781]: <info> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID (none) ((none)) to 08:BD:43:30:43:B5 (TPPW4G_43B5)
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121317] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_action_proc():<10000-1> Rx ACT_ADDBAREQ From :08:bd:43:30:43:b5
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121322] rtl8821ae: 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121323] In process "gedit" (pid 22104):req 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121325] D0 00 3A 01  00 E0 4C 88  12 00 08 BD  43 30 43 B5  
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121331] 08 BD 43 30  43 B5 90 5C  03 00 01 03  10 00 00 00  
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121337] 00 A7 14 78  19 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121339] 
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121367] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_rx_agg_start():<0-0> on ra = 08:bd:43:30:43:b5 tid = 0 seq:2
Dec 19 15:26:29 mts-ubuntu kernel: [ 5729.121380] rtl8821ae-0:rtl_action_proc():<200-1> Tx ACT_ADDBARSP From :00:e0:4c:88:12:00
```

Comment: Kinda looks like the module has debug output enabled.  `modinfo rtl8821ae` shows there is a debug parameter.  Perhaps it's been set to a non-zero value?  Check `/etc/modprobe.d` files and maybe also the kernel boot cmdline (easy to check via `/proc/cmdline`, edit via grub settings or similar. )

Comment: @lornix thanks for your reply. What exactly should I be looking for in /etc/modprobe.d and /proc/cmdline. Sorry to be such a Noob.

Comment: I have just checked modinfo rtl8821ae and the debug level is supposed to be default (0) but that doesn't seem to be the case. What command does one use to make debug:Set equal to (0) for the realtek driver?

Comment: You need to reload the module like this: `sudo rmmod rtl8821ae`, and then `sudo modprobe rtl8821ae debug=0`, or is it 1. Try both.

Comment: Tried what you suggested and set debug=0 and debug=1. Neither worked.

Comment: @mikewhatever Just hit the 5 minute limit on edits. lol I checked for rtl8821ae related file in /etc/modprobe.d in both Ubuntu and Linux Mint and neither seemed to have any thing related. Both directories seem to be the same from memory. Something is different in Mint as it has very little events from the kernel for rtl8821ae, unlike Ubuntu which is constantly writing events at breakneck speed.

Comment: You mean "neither worked" like there were errors, or what? This is exactly why we do not support non-official derivatives here. :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever I mean that after setting debug=0 and debug=1 there was no change. There were no errors after making the change.The syslog was still filling with entries every second. This does not happen in Mint so something is different with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ugh, sounds like someone committed an update with debug output forced on.  But then again, if they did that, you wouldn't be the only one seeing this.  Hmmm.  Add the contents of /proc/cmdline, perhaps it's being forced there.  Although... @mikewhatever 's suggestion would have resolved it.  Dang!  So, process of elimination, it's something in your logging system.  We need to look at the log setup.  Check in /etc/rsyslog.conf and /etc/rsyslog.d/*, looking for a line containing /var/log/syslog. Mine is: '`*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog`'

Comment: mine in rsyslog.d in file50-default.conf is the same as yours. *.*;auth,authpriv.none  -/var/log/syslog I will paste etc/rsyslog.conf in the next box but I don't now how to do the code box business

Comment: Can't do it. Too many characters. Can I update it by using an answer. Will try.

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in 50-default.conf from rsyslog.d. It's too long to paste here and I could not work out how to do it in the answer below. Thanks for your help by the way. I am still confused why the same realtek driver in Linux Mint does not spew out entries from the kernel. Something is different but I just don't know what.

Comment: @lornix I have just checked files /etc/rsyslog.conf and /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf and they are identical in Ubuntu and Mint so the difference must be somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, you might verify the version numbers of the two modules.  _something_ is different.   And you can edit your question (the main part, above) to add the various informations you're asked about. (contents of files and whatnot)  (find module version with `modinfo rtl8821ae` command, look for `vermagic`, mine says `vermagic:       4.2.0-1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions`

Comment: @lornix here are the two versions but it just shows different kernels between Ubuntu and Mint. I'm using Mint 17.3 Rosa and latest recommended kernel. Ubuntu 
vermagic:       3.13.0-74-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
Mint
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686

Comment: @lornix I just upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS kernel to 3.19 linux-generic-lts-vivid. Problem solved. The realtek driver in 3.13 must have been flaky. No dropouts now and no debug output from the kernel for rtl8821ae. So relieved. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Please use the answer section for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 kernel to linux-generic-lts-vivid 13.19 fixed the problem. Driver in original LTS kernel was the problem.